# Drawer rendering inside AppBar element

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, sidebar, drawer

I created a container to limit my app to 600px(sm) width, but when I did it the drawer breaks. Instead of rendering in the container page side, it is inside the appBar.

When the width is more than 600px (the page limit), the drawer is rendering inside the appBar ([picture incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWyrO.png)). When the page is smaller than 600px it renders correct ([picture correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1PO8.png)).

I am using material-ui components, the app bar is position as absolute, because I am implementing on scroll events. To centralize the app bar I use:

```css
    maxWidth: 600,
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      left: "50%",
      transform: "translate(-50%, 0)"
    }
```

Here is codesandbox example code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-drawer-e6vrc?file=/header.js

Answer (score 1):

You should make drawer sibling with AppBar instead of it's children

```js
return (
  <div className={classes.grow}>
    <AppBar className={classes.app_bar}>
      ...
    </AppBar>
    {renderDrawer}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solve my problem :). Now I can try to set the drawer position to start at container right side instead of page, I image that I can move it to the be container limit child. Thanks